# php-fpm, nginx, and headers

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, content-type

Recently I switched a project from standard PHP with Apache, to PHP-FPM with NGINX. I immediately noticed that all JSON requests were returning the text/html content type where previously they returned application/json.

After hours searching google and stack overflow and finding nothing and honestly starting to think I was crazy, I finally realised, purely by accident, that the problem stemmed from setting the Content-Type header twice. Once at the very start of the application's entry point, a default to text/html, and then once again when specifically wanting to send JSON (in the case of an XHR request) by setting application/json.

My question is, why the difference? Why does code that works perfectly fine under Apache and PHP, stop working under NGINX and PHP-FPM? What is it about the combination that makes the second call to header() fail?

And as a follow up, should the code have ever worked under Apache/PHP, or is setting the Content-Type twice inherently bad / frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Content-Type header twice is illegal and therefore the behaviour will be undefined.

See RFC7230 section 3.2.2:

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field name in a message unless either the entire field value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)] or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

Web servers often sanitise the HTTP headers emitted by applications, such as adding missing headers. One assumes that Apache removes the duplicate header whereas `nginx` does not.

Comment: Then why does PHP have the $replace argument at all? Shouldn't it be assumed that if the default behaviour is to replace the header, that PHP will handle this and the duplicate should never even be sent to Apache/NGINX?